# What happened to the T-800 when the cop car crashes into the wall?

Tags: the-terminator-series, the-terminator

At the end of the car chase scene in *The Terminator*, the titular villain makes an escape and isn't seen until later in the film.

Comment: Presumably the terminator either hides under the police car or rapidly flees the area.

Comment: Are you talking about when he crashes the car into the station? A scene where he's hit by the car? Can you provide a clip?

Comment: I remember the scene. It's when Reese and Sarah are surrounded by cop cars in the parking garage after being chased by the terminator, who was driving a cop car, and the terminator had crashed into a wall. When they look at the crashed car, he is gone.

Comment: the: Yes, it was that scene. I actually remember looking at that scene prior to this last time that I had seen The Terminator, which was just yesterday, and found that in slow motion, you can actually see the cyborg jerk back when the car hits the wall. It was a bit weird that it was able to disappear that fast because throughout the whole movie, it seemed very susceptible to terminator like concussions, where it would have to pause after a huge blow, either from a gun shot, the gas truck blowing up, etc.

Comment: @Wanting Answers. I always wondered why the terminator fled from the parking garage, when later in the movie he wipes out an entire police station just to find his targeted victim. He must have been temporarily damaged, yeah that must be it!

Comment: @theguest - ["Why didn't the T-800 Arnold-bot fulfill its mission in the parking garage before the Police arrested Reese?"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/106541/why-didnt-the-t-800-arnold-bot-fulfill-its-mission-in-the-parking-garage-before)

Comment: @Valorum: Does the novelization shed any light on this? :)

Comment: @Valorum. I see. I never knew about this explanation in the novelization, I always assumed it was an oversight on the part of the filmmakers. The movie is full of plot holes, continuity errors and lapses in logic, but I love it just the same.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Not really. It mentions him making his way "on foot" to the hotel which strongly suggests that he just ran away and no-one noticed him do it

Comment: the: Well, it would depend on what police were to it in the future. When looking from the Terminator's perspective, it seems that Skynet was still vulnerable to the fact that the police could have the means to stop it. I mean now days, they have military and SWAT at their disposal. Those weapons would be enough to disable it. Think of the weapon that the T-800 uses over and over again in T-2 Judgement Day against the T-1000. Heck, even that one gun it uses to distract the cops and have zero casualties caused. The solid form of T-800 would be pretty much useless.

Comment: Valorum: Something that big, police would have seen. It's not like the T-1000 which can form puddles at will and slip through cracks. That thing was like a 6 foot wide bodied cybernetic organism.

Comment: @WantingAnswers - Sure, but the popo were hundreds of feet away and it can move surprisingly fast

Answer (score 5):

Watching that scene, there's 35 seconds between when he hits the wall and when anyone looks over to see he's gone.  In that time, he could have exited the passenger door and casually walked away.

Presumably he was damaged, which would explain why he didn't immediately continue the attack.  But he wasn't stunned or anything.  He spends 3 seconds assessing the situation and decides to temporarily flee, then he climbs out the door facing away from everyone and takes a hike.

And there's another overturned car just past the police car, and darkness not far beyond.  Fleeing without being noticed would have been pretty simple.

**Update**:  He was damaged, yes.  I think the next scene after this is where he's in a motel room repairing his face (I could be misremembering).  Heck, if he hadn't been damaged, there's no reason he wouldn't have immediately pressed the attack.  But he wasn't knocked unconscious like a human might have been.  He had plenty of time to assess the situation and decide he needed to flee, and step out the passenger-side door.

The car he hit just before the crash was overturned there, so that'd provide cover for the first dozen feet or so of fleeing.  After that, as you can see near the end of the scene, the street-lights end and it gets dark.  Can't see exactly where, but he might have had only a few feet to go to reach darkness.  And he was wearing dark clothing.

After reaching darkness, there's a street to flee on.

And if you watch the scene, every single cop was focused on the couple in the car, on the guy holding a shotgun.  It's easier to flee if nobody's looking at you.

Comment: That was my though, The policeman looks down the alley and it's pretty dark. The Terminator only needed to make it about twenty feet and it would be entirely invisible to the naked eye in shadow

Comment: For the record, the party line is that he was most certainly stunned and took considerable damage; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/106541/why-didnt-the-t-800-arnold-bot-fulfill-its-mission-in-the-parking-garage-before

Comment: User: I reached out to you because you answered my previous question. My other question was another I asked yesterday and members of this site thought it as being duplicate. The difference in my other question is, from what we know, HOW does he get away without being noticed? For instance, we see the cop looking to the right of the police car. There is NOTHING there, but a wall (no gaps, etc.). Being damaged, the T-800 would have spent some time just trying to erect itself and then make a getaway. We saw this many times when he was shot or had taken a blow off a motorcycle.

Comment: Here is the most previous question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/214540/how-looking-back-at-the-scene-of-when-the-t-800-crashes-the-cop-car-could-it-h